# Exception for REST services for invalid input requests

Tags: java, rest, exception, jersey, throw

I am currently developing `REST` services and throwing `BadRequestException` for all of the following,

```
1. Path parameter is invalid
2. Query parameter is invalid
4. Input request object has missing attributes
```

Is there any specific exceptions for each case like *InvalidParameterException* or so..? Is there any documentation available to learn which exceptions should be thrown on what situations?

Comment: Exception is throwing in Rest client. Do you have used library like spring RestTemplate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's a personal decision and the answer will depend on your needs to have more detailed expceptions or not.

There are two ways to handle errors with JAX-RS:

### Throwing a `WebApplicationException`

That's the approach you are using, which allows you to map exceptions that extend [`WebApplicationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) to HTTP error responses.

I think throwing a [`BadRequestException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BadRequestException.html) is just fine for all the situations mentioned in your question. Just remember adding a detailed message explaining what was wrong.

If you need a more specific exception, you could consider extending the [`BadRequestException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BadRequestException.html) or maybe the [`ClientErrorException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html). The new exceptios could encapsulate the message which explains what the problem with the request. It's up to your needs.

For more details on the exceptions provided by the JAX-RS API, have a look at the [`javax.ws.rs` package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html). If they do not fit your needs, just extend them and create your specific exceptions.

### Using an `ExceptionMapper`

In other cases it may not be appropriate to throw instances of [`WebApplicationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), or classes that extend [`WebApplicationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), and instead it may be preferable to map an existing exception to a response. For such cases it is possible to use a custom exception mapping provider.

Consider, for example, you decide to throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) whenever you received an inapropriate value for your query or path parameters. You can create an [`ExceptionMapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) to map the [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) to a response with the `400` status code:

```java
@Provider
public class IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper 
             implements ExceptionMapper<IllegalArgumentException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        return Response.status(400).entity(exception.getMessage())
                       .type("text/plain").build();
    }
}
```

For more details, have a look at the Jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6665).

Answer (score 1):

All 3 errors sound like client errors, as the client fails to abide by the contract - so I would return a **HTTP 400 Bad Request** - perhaps with an explanation in the body of the response.

Answer (score 0):

I believe usually you would create separate cases depending on how you would like to handle these errors. For example, you will have 3 different exceptions to represent your errors.

Most frameworks then allow you to install ExceptionMappers. These map your exceptions to an HTTP response code. These are documented and you should follow them:

For example: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

In your case for example, I would throw IllegalArgumentExceptions for all those 3 cases and install a mapper, mapping this to a 400 response code with potentially some info. 
This can be for example important since the client consuming your service will not receive your exceptions anyway, but rather analyse the response code of the request. With a 400, a user will then know that the request was invalid and won't be retried. You can have similar cases for all sorts.

To read about exception mappers, for example with the help of jersey:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html

So to your question: 
No, I don't believe there is any best-practise on what Exceptions are thrown from your application. Usually REST frameworks don't have specific exception mappers other than a catch-all mapper that will return a 500 (Internal Server Error)

There is however documentation for REST and the HTTP with regards to which responses should be returned for specific use cases. You should try and design your REST endpoint to conform to those standards for maximum reusability and understandability.

I hope that helps,

Artur